# Trying to represent hashtags in a bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, twitter, data-visualization

I have downloaded tweets and I am trying to represent the different hashtags and how often they are tweeted.

Some data

```
screen_name     location             text                                         created_at          hashtags
  <chr>           <chr>                <chr>                                        <dttm>              <list>  
1 Patrick33079201 "Canada"             "Please sign Romans petition to stop vaccin~ 2021-09-24 23:36:33 <chr [1~
2 wakeupsleepers  "Philippians 3:20 <U+271E>" "@cwt_news When will people wake up?\nhttps~ 2021-09-24 23:35:58 <chr [1~
3 keen_alice      " UK"                "Without  scanning qr code vaccine passport~ 2021-09-24 23:34:57 <chr [1~
4 Sledgeh63514792 ""                   "Mike yeadon warned us about being on a com~ 2021-09-24 23:33:10 <chr [1~
5 PeterHu65796484 ""                   "Mike yeadon warned us about being on a com~ 2021-09-24 23:32:41 <chr [1~
6 thbransfield    "here"               "@ksorbs Wow.\n\nGet the vaccine.  That way~ 2021-09-24 23:32:17 <chr [1~

ggplot(testdata,aes(x=count(unique(hashtags))))+
  geom_bar()
```

I get this error

> Error in abs(x) : non-numeric argument to mathematical function

I want it to count all the occurrences of different hashtags that may be present for each user

Comment: The `hashtags` column is a `list`

Comment: I tried hash<-table(testdata$hashtags) and hash<-as.data.frame(table(testdatahashtags))

Comment: Based on the ones you showed, it is a `list` column `hashtags<list>`.  Can you try the solution posted below.  `table` also doesn't work i.e. `table(as.list(letters))` would give completely different output

Comment: the solution produced a chart, can i use an if condition to show on the graphs only hashtags with over a certain number like 200

Comment: Then you can use a `filter` i.e. `testdata %>%
    unnest(c(hashtags)) %>%
    count(hashtags) %>% filter(n > 200) %>%   ggplot(aes(x = hashtags, y = n)) + 
       geom_col()`

Comment: ok, that works, i think i can figure out the rest from here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the input showed, 'hashtags' is a `list` column.  We may need to `unnest` the column first before applying the `count`.  In addition, `count` requires input as `data.frame/tibble` and not a vector or list

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
testdata %>%
    unnest(c(hashtags)) %>%
    count(hashtags) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = hashtags, y = n)) + 
       geom_col()
```

---

Or if we need a `base R` plot, `unlist` the column, get the frequency count with `table` and use `barplot`

```
barplot(table(unlist(testdata$hashtags)))
```